# Record video on an iPhone while streaming to Mac

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, video, streaming

I would like to live stream using an *iPhone* as the video source, as well as using an external mic, so for that I'll need to merge everything in [*OBS*](https://obsproject.com/) (for example) before streaming.

The problem here is that there are many ways to stream video from *iPhone* to *Mac* or even *Windows* but I would like to record a full quality version too for later publication, directly on the *iPhone*, or on the *Mac* but that would mean that the stream would need to be high enough quality (which the live stream does not have to).

How could I accomplish this? (Applications, QuickTime?)