# Is it possible to stream high-quality ProRes video directly from an iPhone to a Mac?

Tags: iphone, audio, video, macos

This is related to “ [Record video on an iPhone while streaming to Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438209/record-video-on-an-iphone-while-streaming-to-mac) ”, but I think that question could be solved with an HDMI adapter or similar, but I specifically want to do this *without* quality loss.

My goal here is to get the highest quality video out of an iPhone in a studio-ish setting (i.e., near a bunch of computers and a NAS, not out and about in public) *without* having to go through the agony of copying the files over at USB-2.0 speeds with Image Capture.

Comment: There’s a big distinction between *streaming* video and *transferring* video.  Streaming means you’re sending rendered video to an end device.  It *could* be ProRes but will likely change automatically depending on network conditions. Transferring is copying your ProRes Video exactly as is from one device to another for storage/editing.  Which do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want to “stream” but in like… the software engineering sense of “transmit data in real time” and not the colloquial consumer video service sense of “automatically transcode to preserve realtime playback”. I want a huge multi-gigabyte buffer if there’s network congestion, and no reduction in quality. ProRes 4444 has a target bitrate of 330Mbps which fits comfortably in a well configured wifi6 network’s capabilities, so this should be possible.

Comment: For that matter, 330Mbps fits within USB 2! I just want to transmit the footage to a higher performance I/O device *as* it’s being shot, because the transfer takes roughly 20% less time than the recording. After the fact this is agonizing, but if it’s *already* mostly on the mac by the end of shooting, it’s effectively instant.

Comment: Maybe [Continuity](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213244) will do what you’re looking to achieve?

Comment: The word you're looking for is 'tethering'. Tethered still shooting is commonplace, usually using a DSLR, but an iPhone can be persuaded. I can't really find a video equivalent for a phone. In pro setups video is transferred over wireless, idk if it's actual wifi or some equivalent - I work in the TV/film industry, but not on camera, so I see this all the time, but have never had to work with it directly.

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you so much for the magic word to add to my searches here, I can see WAY more results now. In my world "tethered" means "using a mobile device as a network border gateway" so it would not have occurred to me to try that :)

Comment: @Allan I think, maybe, but you'd need some additional software for actually recording the video, as far as I can tell. Unless you can persuade QuickTime to do it somehow? I haven't found any UI for that yet.